# Possible Notations for Content Negotiation Headers?

Tags: http, reference, http-headers, content-negotiation

Where can I find all the possible content *notations* for the following HTTP headers?

- `Accept`
- `Accept-Charset`
- `Accept-Encoding`
- `Accept-Language`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is the HTTP 1.1bis draft. If what you want isn't defined at, or referenced from, https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p3-payload-14#section-6.1 then it probably isn't defined.